# How to detect which side of a KTable join has triggered an update?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

When you are joining two KTables in Kafka, every time one of the two KTables gets updated, your output Ktable gets updated as well.

Imagine you are joining `Customers` with a list of `Orders` which you have reduced appropriately. Imagine again you consume the result of this join to produce special offers and proposal for the end customer:

- You might want to send him a special offer because he has changed address and he is now in an area where you sell product XYZ
- You might want to send him a special offer because his total orders sum at more than 1000$.

In order to implement this, you would need to know every time the join "emits" a new record on the stream, which side of the join determined this new record. What is the appropriate solution to handle this use case?

Answer (score 5):

I think there are two ways to do this:

1. Use a consecutive `.transform()` after the join that store the current join result in a store. If you receive an update, you can compare the new result with the old result and thus determine if the customer data or order data changed. This is a memory intensive solution though.
2. Use a `transform()` before the join (for each input), and augment your records with timestamp or offset information. The join should preserve this information. Thus, in the result, a larger offset/timestamp of the order compared to the customer tells you that the order was updated and triggered this result. This solution is less memory intensive, but might not be 100% exact, depending on your input data (using offsets might not work at all, and timestamps could also be fuzzy depending on the frequency of the updates to your data).

Comment: What kind of store we should use to store the current join ? Any docs?

Comment: Regular key-value-store should do: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html#defining-and-creating-a-state-store